# Update whole or parts of column in a single row on MySQL and Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am having trouble with querying whole or parts of the column in a single row.
I am creating a form that can both create (post) and edit(put) data into the form.

I managed to make the function post and delete work, but put(edit) always return a sql syntax error. The syntax works fine when simulating on phpmyadmin.

What is correct way of doing this? Thanks a lot.

```
exports.putProduct = router.put("/api/product/update/:id", (req, res) => {
  const putData = req.body;
  const idToPutData = req.params.id;
  mySQL.query(
    // "UPDATE `product` SET `category`=?, `productname`=?, `os`=?, `model`=?, `serialnumber`=?, `price`=?, `equipment_condition`=?, `detail`=?, `image`=? WHERE id=?", [putData, idToPutData],
    "UPDATE `product` SET ? WHERE id=?", [putData, idToPutData],
    (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }
  );
});

exports.postProduct = router.post("/api/product/new", (req, res) => {
  const postData = req.body;
  mySQL.query(
    "INSERT INTO `product` SET ?", postData,
    (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    }
  );
});

exports.deleteProduct = router.delete("/api/product/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
  const conDeleteData = { id: req.params.id }
  const idToDelete = req.params.id
  mySQL.query(
    "DELETE FROM `product` WHERE id=?", [idToDelete, conDeleteData],
    (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: "... always return a sql syntax error". What error?

Comment: sqlMessage: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'WHERE id=\'5\'\' at line 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'UPDATE `product` SET  WHERE id=\'5\'' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct way to perform a MySQL query update using Nodejs

```
exports.putProduct = router.put("/api/product/update/:id", (req, res) => {
  const putData = req.body;
  const idToPutData = req.params.id;
  mySQL.query(
    "UPDATE `product` SET `category`=?, `productname`=?, `os`=?, `model`=?, `serialnumber`=?, `price`=?, `equipment_condition`=?, `detail`=?, `image`=? WHERE id=?",
    [putData.category, putData.productname, putData.os, putData.model, putData.serialnumber, putData.price, putData.equipment_condition, putData.detail, putData.image, idToPutData],
    (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    }
  );
});
```